# Using a master VMWware Player Image, allow each terminal server user to run a "copy" of that master, leaving the original unchanged

Tags: windows-server-2012, terminal-server

On my Windows 2012 terminal server I have a common account that maintenance people will login to, and I need each one of them to be able to then run an XP VM to run legacy software.  I'd like to maintain a master copy of this XP VM where I can configure and make changes if required, then each time a user logs into the terminal server they would get a copy of this VM to run when required.  So maintenance user 1 could sign in and run this VM, while maintenance user 2 could sign in as the same username and run another copy of the VM.

Is there a way to store a file somewhere in the user's profile such that when they login they essentially get a copy of the file to use while logged in?

Answer (score 1):

Use [Med-V](http://blogs.technet.com/b/medv/archive/2010/02/16/prescriptive-guidance-for-deploying-the-med-v-client-via-an-electronic-software-distribution-method-such-as-sms-sccm.aspx)

*MED-V 2.0

Microsoft’s with MED-V 2.0 is to provide IT departments with a solution to deliver legacy applications to Windows 7 with the least amount of management overhead. It’s a great solution in IT’s toolbox. From an end-user’s perspective, the legacy application is integrated and presented smoothly and seamlessly. MED-V 2.0 is designed to allow faster and easier deployment when compared to MED-V version 1. MED-V v2 integrates with existing management systems and requires no dedicated management infrastructure. It provides more options for URL redirection, including wildcards. It integrates seamlessly with the Windows 7 My Documents and Desktop directories, and automatically synchronizes the host’s network printers with the virtual workspace. It also provides USB device support, including support for flash storage devices and smartcard readers.*